# Maintain line breaks in output from subshell

Tags: linux, bash

When I execute a subshell to obtain output of a command, the line breaks are lost.

For example:

```
filenames=$(grep 'foobar' /some/dir)
echo $filenames
```

Assuming there is more than 1 file in `/some/dir` that contains the string "foobar", those filenames will be printed in one long space-separated line instead of 1 filename per line.

I can't just use `tr` to convert the spaces back to line breaks since the filenames could have spaces in them anyway.

Is there a way to maintain the line breaks?

Comment: how about using awk and sort? can you do that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Quote the variable to print the newlines:

```
filenames=$(grep 'foobar' /some/dir)
echo "$filenames"
```

Comment: Wow, that's awesomely simple yet not completely obvious at the same time, thanks :)

Comment: @fukawi2  `yet not completely obvious`  You are kind.  I'd say "completely *un*-obvious"

Comment: Can anyone explain why this works? what is the diff here?

Comment: @kfir Double quotes preserve the newlines. Without it, it'll undergo *word splitting*, *pathname expansion* and then `echo` will output each word separated by spaces. When you quote it none of it happens and output is as one (usually) expects. E.g., try `str=$(echo hi1; echo hi2)` and then print with `echo $str` and `echo "$str"` and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

not the most resources friendly, because of pipes ...

```
 grep 'foobar' /some/dir/| | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

Here is an example output:

```
$ grep enc pwman/ui/* | awk '{print $1}'
pwman/ui/cli.py:
pwman/ui/cli.py:
pwman/ui/cli.py:
pwman/ui/cli.py:
pwman/ui/cli.py:
pwman/ui/cli.py:
Binary
$ grep enc pwman/ui/* | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u
Binary
pwman/ui/cli.py:
$
```